# Kotlin + Mockito, matching default arguments

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method signature as:

```
  @JvmOverloads
  fun submit(
    message: PushMessage, 
    targetPackage: String, 
    intercept: Boolean = false) {
```

I'm trying to test it like this:

```
    verify(service.messageBroadcaster, times(1))
      .submit(any(PushMessage::class.java), any(String::class.java))
```

When I try this, Mockito tells me I didn't supply enough argument matchers:

```
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 2 recorded:
```

When I try to test like this, with 3 matchers:

```
    verify(service.messageBroadcaster, times(1))
      .submit(any(PushMessage::class.java), any(String::class.java), any(Boolean::class.java))
```

I get:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
messageBroadcaster.submit(
    <any com.foo.common.message.PushMessage>,
    <any java.lang.String>,
    <any boolean>
);
-> at com.foo.engine.push.MessageBroadcaster.submit(MessageBroadcaster.kt:224)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
messageBroadcaster.submit(
    {"id":"1","event":"test"},
    "com.foo.engine"
);
```

Note I'm using this custom `any` function:

```
private fun <T> any(type: Class<T>): T = Mockito.any(type)
```

To work around the "any cannot be null" problem when using Mockito with Kotlin.

Comment: I suspect a difference between Boolean and boolean is what's going on (the primitive wrapper versus the primitive).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the native mockitokotlin2 `any()` or `anyOrNull()` thats handle null values and looks like this `any<String>() anyOrNull<String>()`

```
verify(service.messageBroadcaster, times(1))
  .submit(anyOrNull<PushMessage>(), anyOrNull<String>(), anyOrNull<Boolean>())
```

Comment: mockitokotlin2 is no longer supported. You need to use org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin - it's the same library, but supported. https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin